# How to find uncapitalised characters and replace them with capitals in python

Tags: python

So, this time, my challenge asks me to get an input from the user, and my python code has to check through the code and find any uncapitalised characters that should be capitalised - if there is a " i " found in the text, this will be replaced with " I ", and any (non-space) uncapitalised character after any !?. should be capitalised (". cheese" would be replaced with ". Cheese"). My code can so far find the uncapitalised "i"s and replace them but cannot yet replace uncapitalised characters found after !?. (after a space). Here is my code so far:

```
import re

def capitalise():
    string = str(input("Please input a uncapitalised string to be capitalised:"))
    string = string.replace(" i ", " I ")
    a = string.find('\. [a-z]')
    b = '\. [A-Z]'
    string = string.replace(a,b)
    print(string)

def main():
    capitalise()
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Anybody have any idea on how to do the last part?

Comment: There are `capitalize` and `upper` methods on string objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick example with reqular expressions

```
words = '  a string i want to be capitalised: string2 . string 3 !string 4 :   string 5 !!? string6.'
for match in re.findall('(^\s*\w)|(\s*[\.\?\!\:]\s*\w)|(\s+i\s+)', words) : 
    words = words.replace(''.join(match), ''.join(match).upper(), 1)
```

Result :

```
print(words)
'  A string I want to be capitalised: String2 . String 3 !String 4 :   String 5 !!? String6.'
```

Comment: This was amazingly useful, just a couple of questions, what do "^s*\w" and "\s+i\s+" mean/what do they do - is it that ^s is a space, *\w is a lower case character, and "\s+i\s+" just searches for a lower case "i" surrounded by 2 spaces?

Comment: `^` is the beggining of the string, `\s` is space `\w` matches a-z, A-Z, 0-9 .  You can find more details [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_reg_expressions.htm)

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like this:

```
>>> word = ".cheese"
>>> def return_index(word):
...     for i, x in enumerate(word):
...         if x.isalpha():
...             return i
... 
>>> index = return_index(word)
>>> index
1
>>> if index:
...     word.replace(word[index],word[index].upper(), 1)
... 
'.Cheese'
```

Comment: Thank you find this but it only works with the specific instance of ".cheese" and will only replace the character after the fullstop with a capitalised character, it does not incorporate the capitalising of " i ". Also it does not include a space after the fullstop, unlike in normal text. Is there any way of fixing this?

Comment: @ZakGriffith I just given the idea you can proceed, its not the full solution